Change label based input value
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\newcounter{question}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\Roman{question}}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729773/10898
\newenvironment{question}[2]{% #1 = points, #2 = question text
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \stepcounter{question}%
  \noindent{\bfseries \thequestion. #2{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hspace{2em}\mbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)\parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}%
  \vspace{\topsep}
}{\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}{4}{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following.}
\end{question}
\begin{question}{2}{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following.}
\end{question}
\begin{question}{1}{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following.}
\end{question}
\end{document}


This produces the intended effect but I would like instead of (4), (2) or (1) only, that it produces (4 points each), (2 points each), (1 point each). Therefore, if the user inputs 1, that it uses point and for any  number greater than one that it ouputs points.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\newcounter{question}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\Roman{question}}
\newcommand\pointvalue{points}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729773/10898
\newenvironment{question}[2]{% #1 = points, #2 = question text
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \stepcounter{question}%
  \ifnum#1=1
    \def\pointvalue{point}%
  \fi
  \noindent{\bfseries \thequestion. #2{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hspace{2em}\mbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1 \pointvalue{} each)\parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}%
  \vspace{\topsep}
}{\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}{4}{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following.}
\end{question}
\begin{question}{2}{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following.}
\end{question}
\begin{question}{1}{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following.}
\end{question}
\end{document}

